# convert XML file into a HTML page

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I try to convert an XML file to a HTML page but nothing is displayed. in the following, i put the XML code, the xslt code and the HTML page. Thank you for your help.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="fg.xsl" ?>

<cuimodel>
<window id='window1'>
<div>
<label id='label1'> searchPreference </label> 
<label id='label12'> seeFirst </label> 
<combobox id='CB1' name='criteriaCB'>
<item>promotions</item>
<item>BestRated </item>
</combobox>
</div>

<div>
<label id='label2'> mon </label> 
<label id='label21'> second  </label> 
<combobox id='CB2' name='DispLayout'>
<item>GridLayout</item>
<item>listlayout</item>
</combobox> 
</div>

<div>
<label id='label13'> Preference </label> 
<label id='label122'> see </label> 
<combobox id='CB3' name='CT'>
<item>HighContrast</item>
<item>LowContrast</item>
</combobox>
</div>
<button>cancel</button>
<button>ok</button>
</window>
</cuimodel>
```

XSLT code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/"> 
<html> 
<body> 
<xsl:for-each select="div">
<xsl:for-each select="label">
<label>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</label>
<select>
<xsl:for-each select="combobox">
<option>
<xsl:value-of select="item"/>
</option>
</xsl:for-each>
</select>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="button">
<button>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</button>
</xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:for-each>
</body> 
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the html page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SReT.png)

Comment: (1) Your XML input is malformed.  The `<cuimodel>` end tag is presented as a start tag.  (2) After fixing that, try performing the transform and looking at the output (directly, not via a browser).  Hmm.  Do you see anything to explain why the browser renders a blank page?  I do.

Comment: Hi John, I fixed the "cuimodel" tag but the browser renders a blank page

Comment: ... which is exactly what I said it does, right before I described how you can see for yourself *why* it does.

Comment: Hi John, to perform the transformation, I use the online xslt (http://xslttest.appspot.com/), and I don't understand why it returns the blank page

Comment: if you ran the XML input currently presented in this question through the transform currently presented in this question via the tool to which you linked, and, after looking at the transformed output, you do not understand why a browser renders that as a blank page, then I'm afraid we cannot help you.  You are not prepared to understand anything we might say other than "here's a working solution for you."  And your existing code is much too far away from a working solution for it to be likely that one of us will hand you one.

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues, starting with:

```
<xsl:for-each select="div">
```

This selects nothing, because you are in the context of the `/`root node. To select `div` from here, you need:

```
<xsl:for-each select="cuimodel/window/div">
```

---

Note also that:

```
<xsl:value-of select="item"/>
```

returns nothing, because the `item` element has no text value. Perhaps you meant:

```
<xsl:value-of select="item/@value"/>
```

but that too is problematic, since a `combobox` has multiple `item` children.

---

There's probably more, but this should get you started.

Comment: Hi Michael, I added a text value to "the item" markup, I also modify the select "div" but nothing is displayed